# How to save , display and edit checkbox in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have done the save part. In the below code I am showing how I displayed the saved data and how I am trying to edit the form on click of edit button.

This is my angularjs code.

```
  var module=angular.module('myApp',[]);
 module.controller('myController',function($scope, $http){
 $scope.post.users = [];
  $scope.technology = [{
      id: 1,
      name: 'HTML'
      },
     {
      id: 2,
      name: 'PHP'
     },
     {
     id: 3,
     name: 'Jquery'
     },
    {
     id: 4,
     name: 'AJAX'
    },
    {
    id: 5,
    name: 'Angular JS'
    }];

 // This is the data I fetch and display in form when edit button is clicked

  $scope.editUser = function(user){
    $scope.empData = {
        id: user.id,
        firstname : user.firstname,
        lastname : user.lastname,
        email : user.email,
        mobile : user.mobile,
        city : user.city,
        address : user.address,
        experience : user.experience,
        designation : user.designation,
        //technology : user.technology,
        relocate : user.relocate,
        salary : user.salary
    };
    $scope.empData.technology=user.technology;
}
});
```

This is my HTML Code

```
  <body data-ng-app="myApp" data-ng-controller="myController" data-ng-init="init()">
  <label>First Name</label>
  <input type="text" name="firstname" data-ng-model="empData.firstname" /></br>

  <label>Technical Skills</label>
  <span ng-repeat="tech in technology">
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="tech.selected" value={{tech.name}} /> {{tech.name}}
</span>
</body>
```

I have displayed the data, But in edit how do I make the checkbox checked when clicked on edit

This the way I displayed data

```
    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th width="5%">#</th>
                            <th width="10%">Firstname</th>
                            <th width="10%">Technical Skills</th>
                            <th width="10%">Edit</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr data-ng-repeat="user in post.users | orderBy : '-id'">
                            <th scope="row">{{user.id}}</th>
                            <td> {{user.firstname}} </td>
                            <td> {{user.technology}} </td>
                            <td> <span data-ng-click="editUser(user)"> Edit</span></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

Comment: Where is the edit button. Post the complete code.

Comment: @VVK I have updated the code.Please check

Answer (score 0):

First: don't use `value` if you are using `ng-model`. Let angular handle it.

Second: What are you trying to do? If you are trying to edit the name when clicking the checkbox, add another input with type text, bind it to `name` and use ng-disable to enable it.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10508210)

Comment: It went beyond a critique or request. I thought it may be causing the problem. Also, in my second point, I provided details and steps for a possible solution. I'm not saying "ur code suks lol"

Comment: Surely no need to add another text box here. Op is missing the `tech.selected` in his main scope object which is causing the issue. Angular is smart enough to handle checkbox for true value.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing `ng-model="tech.selected"` but from `$scope.technology` object you have no `selected` key. First you need to add that like below

```
 $scope.technology = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'HTML',
      selected: false
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: 'PHP',
      selected: false
    },
    {
     id: 3,
     name: 'Jquery',
     selected: false
    },
    {
     id: 4,
     name: 'AJAX',
     selected: false
    },
    {
      id: 5,
      name: 'Angular JS',
      selected: false
    }];
```

Now when you go to edit page, you must be getting already save data wherein the value of `tech.selected` is true for selected checkboxes. When you will iterate that data using `ng-repeat` it will display checkbox selected for `tech.selected = true`

Hence assuming, you have `technology` object as below in edit page

```
$scope.technology = [
        {
          id: 1,
          name: 'HTML',
          selected: true // This will appear checked
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: 'PHP',
          selected: false
        },
        {
         id: 3,
         name: 'Jquery',
         selected: true // This will appear checked
        },
        {
         id: 4,
         name: 'AJAX',
         selected: false
        },
        {
          id: 5,
          name: 'Angular JS',
          selected: true //This will aprear checked
        }
];
```

This fiddle will explain you better http://jsfiddle.net/uf4c87t4/

Comment: This works when I get the data in which you have shown. But I am getting the checkbox data in the format AJAX,PHP,JQUERY when clicked on edit button. How do I change this format to the format [{id:1,name:'HTML'},{id:2,name:'PHP'},{id:3,name:'Jquery'},{id:4,name:'AJAX'}{id:5,name:'Angular JS'}]

Comment: You need to add the `selected` in you data since you have used that in data binding `ng-model=tech.selected` else if not `selected` you must have something in boolean value to make you checkbox checked or unchecked. else there is no way.